# Learning C: strange code, what does it do?

Tags: c, macros

I'm exploring wxWidgets and at the same time learning C/C++.  Often wxWidgets functions expect a `wxString` rather than a `string`, therefore wxWidgets provides a macro `wxT(`*yourString*`)` for creating `wxString`s.  My question concerns the expansion of this macro.  If you type `wxT("banana")` the expanded macro reads `L"banana"`.  What meaning does this have in C?  Is L a function here that is called with argument "banana"?

Comment: The 'L' stands for 'long' and also appears when declaring `long double` constants, e.g., "10.11L" See ANSI C89 standard, section 6.1.3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `"banana"` is the word written using 1-byte ASCII characters.
- `L"banana"` is the word written using multi-byte (general 2=byte UNICODE) characters.

Comment: On most 32-bit linux systems (I'm not sure about 64-bit) multi-byte characters are usually 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

L is a flag on strings to let it know it's a wide (unicode) string.

Answer (score 2):

The L tells your compiler that it's a unicode string instead of a "normal" one.